# Eclipse :XML is disappeared from the Project

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am using Spring 2.5 with Eclipse Helios .
By mistake , i have placed my  beans.xml under src folder and not inside the bin folder  and i  executed the java client under Eclipse IDE .
As usual it gave me a Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

But when i manually  went to the project Resource  to copy the beans.xml to bin folder , surprisingly the beans.xml is dissappeared .

Please tell me , is this a common behaviour ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your bin folder is where the compiled classes is stored. You can check Project Settings, Java Build Path for that.

Whenever you clean the project, this folder will be emptied and then filled up with compile results. So this is a common behaviour.